# What is the difference between Narrow Conversion & Narrow Casting in Java?

Tags: java

What is the difference between Narrow Conversion & Narrow  Casting in Java?

I can't find the answer....

Comment: Have a look at the document - https://salitha94.blogspot.com/2018/03/conversion-and-casting-in-java.html

Comment: That's not a good tutorial, if you ask me.  For example, it says that `byte b = 100;` is a widening conversion, when actually it is a narrowing conversion from `int` to `byte`.  (Which works for reasons to complicated to explain in a comment :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Narrow conversion**

Narrow conversion is needed when you convert from a lager size to a smaller size. But there is an issue because the data types are incompatible, so it will not happen automatically. So usually we can not talk about narrow conversion but this will apply in some cases specially using assignment operators , such as += , -= , *= , %= , /=.This will automatically convert larger data type to a smaller data type.

```
    class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long x=123456;
        byte b=10;
    
        b+=x; //Legal, no need to cast
        System.out.println(x+" : "+b);

    }
}
```

**Narrow casting**

This will convert a larger type to a smaller size type. Narrow casting must be done manually by placing the type in parentheses in front of the value.

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double d=65.12345;
        char ch;
        ch=(char)d; 
        System.out.println(d+" "+ch); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A type cast is the general term for the Java syntax `'(' <type> ')' <expression>`.  A narrowing cast is a type cast that converts from a wider (larger) type to a smaller (narrower) type.

The term "narrowing conversion" refers to the conversion that is performed by a narrowing type cast.  If you need a more precise explanation of the relationship between the two, please read JLS [5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1), [5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) and [15.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16).

Note that a narrowing conversion also occurs in contexts where there is an *implicit* cast.  For example:

```
byte b = 1;
b += 1;
```

The `b += 1` expression is specified as being equivalent to `b = (byte)(b + 1)`.  The narrowing is needed here because the `b + 1` computation is actually an 32 bit integer addition producing a 32 bit integer result.

Narrowing conversions are also used in `++` and `--` operators ... for the same reasons as above.  The relevant references are JLS [15.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) and [15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Finally, narrowing conversions can also occur in assignments involving simple assignment of compile-time constant expressions to certain primitive types.  For example:

```
byte b = 1;  // primitive narrowing conversion of an
             // int value to a byte.
```

See JLS [5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) for the rules that govern this.